# Lex - How to run / compile a lex program on commandline

Tags: c, lex

I am very new to Lex and Yacc. I have a Lex program. Example: `wordcount.l`

I am using windows and putty.

I am just trying to run this file..

1. Does the `wordcount.l` file go on the C drive?
2. Do I compile the Lex program and it generates a `.c` program and then what do I run?

I tried on the command-line: Lex `wordcount.l`

but I just get file not found...

wordcount.l

```
%{  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int charCount=0;
int wordCount=0;
int lineCount=0;
%}
%%
\n      {charCount++; lineCount++;}   
[^ \t\n]+   {wordCount++; charCount+=yyleng;}
.       {charCount++;}

%%
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char** argv;
{           
if (argc > 1)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    yyin = file;
}

yylex();
printf("%d   %d   %d\n", charCount, wordCount, lineCount);
}
```

In putty how do I compile and run this program?

Comment: Lex or flex?  The behaviours are different.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You first have to go to the directory which the file `wordcount.l` is in using `cd`.  Then using `lex wordcount.l` will make the file `lex.yy.c`.  To the run the program you need compile it with a **c compiler** such as gcc.   With gcc you can compile it using `gcc -lfl lex.yy.c`.  This will create `a.out`  which can be run using `./a.out`

Comment: I tried cd c:\  then hit enter then typed in lex wordcount.l and i still get an error: no such file or directory

Comment: @icelated Are you using putty to connect to a remote host(sever)? If so you need to copy the file to that host first.

Comment: I am using putty. What do you mean copy the file to the host? you mean copy the file to the server at school? Can i use SSH instead?

Comment: I believe the pure Lex uses `-ll` and Flex uses `-lfl`.  Also, for reliability, you should list the library after the object or source files, so: `gcc lex.yy.c -ll` should be correct.  Of course, the Windows prompt begs the question of 'Which version of Lex is in use?', since the original Lex was not ported there.  It might be Flex after all, or maybe MKS Lex (& Yacc), or ... something else.

Comment: I have the same problem when i write lex wordcount.l i get 'lex' is not recognized as an internal or external command Do i need to install something fist and if I do what is it ?

Answer (score 6):

```
lex file.l
gcc lex.yy.c -ly -ll
./a.out
```

These also works. I am using this in Ubuntu 14.04.