# Compiling a Lex program on OS X

Tags: c, lex

Is anyone able to better inform me on successfully compiling a Lex source file on OS X in terminal. I have written in `HelloWorld.l` the following:

```
%%

"hello world"    printf("GOODBYE\n");
.                ;

%%
```

Within the console I executed `lex HelloWorld.l` followed by `gcc lex.yy.c -ll` and `./a.out` receiving a blank state within my window and no result.

I am basing my knowledge on this topic from the source [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54bo1qaHAfk) and similar Stack question [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859710/lex-how-to-run-compile-a-lex-program-on-commandline).

Comment: Your `.` rule ignores unmatched inputs.  For debugging, it's best to print ignored inputs (maybe to standard error, maybe with identifying text).  However, even that won't help until you provide it some input to ignore — the program will wait for you to type something, anything.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, would you be able to recommend a basic program to fulfil my general purpose or to further my understanding.

Comment: Simply change the `;` after the `.` to `printf("Ignored (%c)\n", yytext[0]);`.  This will print a line of output for each ignored character (such as the newline after you type `hello world`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

flex, will by default, read from standard input. You need to actually provide it some input. You can do `echo "hello world" | ./a.out` and you should see your result.

Comment: Thank you for responding, may I ask you now about compiling the wordcount.l program from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859710/lex-how-to-run-compile-a-lex-program-on-commandline)? Specifically, would you be able to explain how to provide input such as the file referenced within this code.

Comment: @aitia please ask a new question for that

Comment: @aitía: If you have a file `xyz.data` that you want to send to your program, use `./a.out < xyz.data` (or, if you have multiple files, consider `cat file1.data file2.data | ./a.out`).