# Lex error: type specifier missing

Tags: c, lex

Following recommendation from a stack user and instructions within the following stack question:

[Lex - How to run / compile a lex program on commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859710/lex-how-to-run-compile-a-lex-program-on-commandline)

I receive the following error after executing `lex wordcount.l` and `gcc lex.yy.c` -ll on OS X and my console window:

```
wordcount.l:16:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
main(argc, argv)
```

Is anyone able to help me resolve this error along with further explanation?

Specifically how would I specify the file such that it is found. Thank you.

Comment: Lex is a very old program, so it outputs C language based on pre-ANSI standards. In particular, it doesn't declare main to return int, because early C compilers assume all functions return int unless told otherwise. Nowadays, that's seen as bad practice, hence the warning. But it will compile and run fine anyway.

Comment: @lee: lex doesn't declare main at all. That's the user's responsibility. (Using the main in libl doesn't involve a declaration.) Also, modern flex versions generate warning-free C code compilable with C99 or C11 (or even C++).

Comment: Look at lines 16-18 of your code.  Change it to `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  If there are mentions of `argc` or `argv` before the opening brace `{` of the body of `main()`, remove them.  But if you’re going to do much programming with Lex, you need to brush up on your C to a point where you don’t need to ask this question.