# How to run / compile a lex program on commandline in Windows

Tags: lex

I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859710/lex-how-to-run-compile-a-lex-program-on-commandline). That one works fine with Linux but don't work for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, use these commands:

```
lex file.l

gcc lex.yy.c

a.exe
```

But make sure your PC has `lex` installed.
You can learn more about the installation [here](https://codedost.com/flex/) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For windows using flix and bison making a.exe

```html
flex filename
gcc lex.yy.c
start a.exe
```